# Why the hashlib and hmac are generating different hash values?

Tags: python, hmac, hashlib

In Python 2.7,

```
my = "my"
key = "key"
print(hashlib.sha256(my + key).hexdigest())
print(hmac.new(my, key, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest())
```

output,

```
5e50f405ace6cbdf17379f4b9f2b0c9f4144c5e380ea0b9298cb02ebd8ffe511
15a55993a27e0de7a4c4daa67a7c219199a464ca283797f545b783cce07b38a5
```

or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836100/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-mac-message-authentication-code

Answer (score 28):

This is because `hmac` uses the provided `key` to generate a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and make the hash more strong, while `hashlib` only hashes the provided message.

By looking at the `hmac` module [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/65c412586901/Lib/hmac.py), you will find how to achieve the same behaviour as `hmac` using the `hashlib` module, here the used algorithm (it's not the original one, i stripped some checkings to have just the interesting part):

```
import hashlib

MESSAGE = "msg"
KEY = "key"

trans_5C = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x5C) for x in xrange(256)])
trans_36 = "".join ([chr (x ^ 0x36) for x in xrange(256)])

outer = hashlib.sha256()
inner = hashlib.sha256()

KEY = KEY + chr(0) * (inner.block_size - len(KEY))

outer.update(KEY.translate(trans_5C))
inner.update(KEY.translate(trans_36))
inner.update(MESSAGE)
outer.update(inner.digest())

result = outer.hexdigest()
print result # prints 2d93cbc1be167bcb1637a4a23cbff01a7878f0c50ee833954ea5221bb1b8c628
```

The same directly using `hmac`:

```
import hashlib
import hmac

result = hmac.new(KEY, MESSAGE, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
print result # prints 2d93cbc1be167bcb1637a4a23cbff01a7878f0c50ee833954ea5221bb1b8c628
```

So when using `hmac`, it doesn't only hashes the given message using the specified hashing algorithm, it also uses the key to complexify the hash.