# Is Mac equivalent to a hash and encrypt function?

Tags: java, android-studio, cryptography, hmac

I am currently learning the cryptography on Android Studio. I am following the tutorial of Jakob Jenkov (http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-cryptography/index.html). It is said that "A MAC is a message digest which has been encrypted with a secret key.". I wanted to make sure and tried to compare the result of the mac function compare to the result of the same data being hash and encrypt. I got different bytes at the end and don't understand why.

Can someone explain this ?

Here is my code :

```
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    byte[] keyBite = new byte[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15};
    String algorithm = "RawBytes";
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBite, algorithm);
    mac.init(keySpec);

    byte[] data = "CedricCrypto".getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] macBytes = mac.doFinal(data);

    // IS MAC = Hash + Encrypt
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec);
    byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(data);
    byte[] encrypt = cipher.doFinal(digest);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Difference between a Hash and MAC (Message Authentication code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2836100/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hash-and-mac-message-authentication-code)

Comment: Thank you for your answer but unfortunately it does not. I understand the difference between both, I just wanted to “recreate” the mac function with the 2 functions it is composed of (Hash + encryption). In my code, what I was expected is that my variable macBytes and Encrypt are equal, but they aren’t, and I don’t understand why. 
I can try to explain with math: if I understood well, Mac function (M() ) is equivalent to Hash function (H() ) followed by Encryption function (E() ). So M(x) = E(H(x)). But in my example, where x = “CedricCrypto”, M(x) != E(H(x)).

Comment: Check [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hmac-and-a-hash-of-data).

Comment: The HMAC-algorithms are <b>not</b> a combination of a Hash-function and an Encryption function, for further information you should read the RFCs (Basic HMAC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2104 and advanced for SHA256/384/512Hmac: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4868).